# using three.js can I place a viewport in a scene between near field and far field

Tags: webgl, three.js, viewport, frustum, perspectivecamera

I am unsure if what I am trying to achieve is possible using three.js

What I aim to do is place the viewport within the frustum.
I want to create a 3d environment in which objects can appear between the viewport and the camera.
So if I move the camera then it appears that the object is rendered in 3d in front of the screen - i.e. the generated parallax gives the impression that it is projected out of the screen when things move.

I just can't find a way to do it. I am certain I did it a number of years ago in flash, I thought I would try three.js and webGL.

[image]